# problem my wp site redirect to another url website

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, themes, rss2

I just uploaded a Wordpress theme onto my Website.
I get url redirects to website when I am browsing though my website.
The malicious site it links to clickbank.com.
I have scanned all my files with TAC and exploit scanner, but it did not pick up anything.
this picture may help you to find the problem from Entries RSS. 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/msiyA.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

check function.php or search for `windows.location` code in all project repo 
you can search all code by **notepad++**

Comment: This is not uncommon and could even be in your theme.  If you obtain your theme from unreliable sources hackers are known to embed malware: https://secure.wphackedhelp.com/blog/wordpress-malware-redirect-hack-cleanup/

Comment: @Nelles yes sure , problem in 'header.php' . must search all file of theme and project to find it

Comment: 2 possible options (a) bring this issue to the attention of the vendor they may offer remedy  (b) do word search on the entire unzipped theme folder.  Problem is they could splice together the malicious domain so it will not be detectable. My recommendation is bail on the theme if it is feasible.  Bad themes can consume a great deal of time.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be a direct and final answer, because there are many possibilities.
You may also tell us what is your theme or installed plugins too if they are free for download, we may try.

You seems to be testing in localhost., IMO you may try to eliminate all possible factors first.

Did you install any plugins? (if so)Did you test also the plugins?
Did you scan your database for this link?
Sometimes this kind of problem also appear from Database side since some problematic plugin may put those link in DB, apart from using exploit scanner, you might have to manually check once.

After all, did you also try a clean install to test the theme?

In addition, if it is a very Wordpress specific questions, you may consider posting in [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thank you for your answer, the theme is proreview and the only plugin i did install are "Theme Authenticity Checker (TAC)" and "exploit scanner" yes it's in localhost to see if i can clean it i checked the database and i didn't find the link appear on the picture above, what do you mean by clean install

Comment: I mean you can try to install another Wordpress without anything to test the theme to see if it is still the case.

Comment: yes i did but unfortunately, i tried to cheack the clickbank link manualy on each php page but i didn't find it,

Comment: I have searched your mentioned themes, it seems to be a premium theme that need to purchase before download. Did you follow the installation instruction and Did you contact the author for solutions? According to the error screen you have post, the error shows a javascript alike code inside. Before installing the theme, did you try a standard theme to see if your localhost server setup rightfully?

Comment: yes it's a premium theme and i bought it with 69$ :( i tried to contact them but i got no answer, yes did try the standard and it works fine but after i install the new theme i got this and it redirect me to another website, i deleted the new theme and i found the standard theme also have this screen but without redirection !! sorry for my english !!

Comment: if you have a testing server to put it online and let us use the administration for test, I think we can help out.